# Java converting integers to strings and calculating it

Tags: java, string, integer, jtextfield

Can anyone explain to me why my Homework keeps retuning a value of 1.0, I asked my teacher and he tells me "langauges are very similar I do not remember in this languge -.-..... you should not be learning this because you are in java 1 not java 2" ...... anyway im trying to get ahead and teach myself

```
              /**
 *  Author Rich Talcik, Do not Edit or modify
 *  Homework assignment2 
 *  09/11/13
 *  Problem 2.7 page 109
 *  
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel jlabel;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("home work");

    JTextField tfAnswer = new JTextField("Click to find travel Time");
    JTextField tfSpeed = new JTextField("Remvoe Text & Enter Speed here");
    JTextField tfDistance = new JTextField("Remove Text & Enter Distance Here");

    float dSpeed;
    float dDistance;
    String sTotal;
    String sSpeed;
    String sDistance;

     public shapeDrawing() {
         super(new BorderLayout());
         JButton button = new JButton("Calculate my Travel Time");

         //Converting the speed to an Integer from a String



         button.addActionListener(this);


         tfSpeed.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {




            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tfSpeed.setText("");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
         });

         tfDistance.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {


            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tfDistance.setText("");
                tfAnswer.setText("");
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

         });

         add(tfSpeed, BorderLayout.AFTER_LINE_ENDS);
         add(tfDistance, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

         add(tfAnswer, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
         add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));

 }


     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

         sSpeed = tfSpeed.getText();
         dSpeed = Integer.valueOf(sSpeed);

         //Converting Distance to integer from string
         sDistance = tfSpeed.getText();
         dDistance = Integer.valueOf(sDistance);             


         final float fTotal = (dDistance / dSpeed);


         tfAnswer.setText(String.valueOf(fTotal));
 }
```

can someone explained why tfAnswer.setText keeps returning the value of 1.0

Comment: "...you should not be learning this because you are in java 1 not java 2" nitpick for your prof: Java 1 and 2 were 15 years ago; most people nowadays are using 6 or 7 (and even the former is no longer updated)

Comment: @DennisMeng - I'm positive he meant a "Java 1" class, like "Java 101", "Java 102", etc.

Comment: What kind of teacher doesn't know basic things about what he's teaching, and actively tries to stop his students from learning?!

Comment: @ChrisForrence Quite possible; though I'm used to hearing "100-level class" or "200-level class." I recognize it could just be me though.

Comment: what chris said supposedly its a not a 400 level class (im ina  community college) and its actually a 200 level class, we will just be using system.println for most of the class and not really learning about applets or JFrames because that's level 2, 400 lvl class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should read tfDistance instead of tfSpeed

```
         sSpeed = tfSpeed.getText();
         dSpeed = Integer.valueOf(sSpeed);

         //Converting Distance to integer from string
         sDistance = tfSpeed.getText(); //!!! copy-past error
         dDistance = Integer.valueOf(sDistance);
```

Should be

```
         sSpeed = tfSpeed.getText();
         dSpeed = Integer.valueOf(sSpeed);

         //Converting Distance to integer from string
         sDistance = tfDistance.getText(); 
         dDistance = Integer.valueOf(sDistance);
```

Comment: thank you! I would of never caught that, typo on my fault thanks I will accept in a couple mins (4 I think it says)

Answer (score -1):

Basically, you're still dividing an integer by an integer (which is then cast to a float). Try this instead:

```
// Multiplying by 1.0 casts that answer to a float, so the
//     division by dSpeed will also result in a float.
float fTotal = (1.0 * dDistance) / dSpeed;
```

Comment: even though he's doing Integer.parseInt the variables dDistance and dSpeed are actually floats

Comment: Ah, good catch. @DHall. I had assumed that they were integers; shows what assuming does!